# Insert or update table using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, insert, insert-update

I have some records to import. It's ok the first time when they are being inserted. If I try to import the same data again I receive a org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint. How can I update the records in the database if the data is the same/or changed and insert if it's new data using JDBC?

```
public void store(Object entity) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (this.updateEntity((XEntity) entity) == 0) {
            this.insertEntity((XEntity) entity);
        }

        ...

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        ...
    }
}

private int updateEntity(XEntity entity) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = this.getUpdatePreparedStmt();
    ...
    return prepStmt.executeUpdate();
}

private void insertEntity(XEntity entity) throws SQLException {
    ...
    this.getInsertPreparedStmt().executeUpdate();
}
```

The problem is fixed now. I've provided an answer below.

Comment: You seem to be in the fairly early stages of your implementation.  Have you considered using JPA or Hibernate instead to handle persistence? Are there any particular requirements that necessitates low-level JDBC-access?

Comment: You should figured out why "this.updateEntity((XEntity) entity) == 0".

Comment: XEntity is my data that is imported. I'm modifying a project that is done with JDBC, so I can't use Hibernate.

Comment: Data will be imported and for each record a decision should be made to insert or update into my table

Comment: the code looks like it could work. So the problem lies probably in your table contraints and/or the inserted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test logic works.

```
if (this.updateEntity((XEntity) entity) == 0) {
    this.insertEntity((XEntity) entity);
}
```

The problem was in the method that updated the record. The WHERE clause in the update prepared statement was using different data(data containing spaces) so updateEntity would always return 0. That was the reason why only inserts were made, instead of updates. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using postgres SQL 'MERGE' or 'REPLACE'

Comment: Yes, just execute the merge or replace query through JDBC (maybe in your updateEntity method?)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the [UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-update.html) command as a string through JDBC.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069718/postgres-insert-if-does-not-exist-already) SO post, you will have to write 2 statements.

Comment: Is there a way to detect that it is a update or insert. Or can I try to update and it it fails on the catch exception block insert a record. Is it a recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same method to insert and update your data, you'll need to check if the data exists first. The SQL command used to insert a new object is `INSERT`, whereas the one used to update an element is `UPDATE`. So, what you could do is do a `SELECT` to check if your data is already here, and then do an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` based on the results.

However, this is a workaround. You would really need to clarify your implementation, and make different methods whether you are adding or updating data. Business-side, these are clearly two very different functions, so one method for both seems to me like a design problem.