# What is the correct way to Insert an image into Postgres with python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I attempted to adapt the examples [here](http://iamtgc.com/using-python-to-load-binary-files-into-postgres/)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342031/443779)

```
import psycopg2
#Given media_id and image_url and conn object
image_data = urllib2.urlopen(image_url).read()
sql =("INSERT INTO images (media_id, data) 
SELECT %s
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT media_id FROM images WHERE media_is = CAST(%s as TEXT) ")
data_insert_image = (media_id, psycopg2.Binary(image_data))
cursor.execute(sql_insert_image, data_insert_image)
conn.commit()
```

Results is:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Which makes sense to me as the image is not a `String`; however, I don't know how to insert properly. How should the insertion be performed?

Comment: You have two SQL statements in your query. I would split them in two. The insert statement should work fine with ```psycopg2.Binary```

Comment: @nathancahill breaking it out into two queries doesn't solve the type error on the image insert

Comment: You're doing an incorrect upsert there - it won't work in the face of concurrency. It's not immediately clear to me why Psycopg2 doesn't like this query; `psycopg2.Binary(image_data)` is indeed the correct approach for dealing with bytea data. Your query is also nonsense; the `INSERT` takes `(media_id, data)` but you've only supplied an argument for `media_id` in the `SELECT`-list.

Comment: Please show what happens when you just try to do a simple insert (since this is about binary handling); keep the upsert mess for later. Regarding upserts, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your heavily redacted code has many problems, some already pointed in the comments. I hope this example is reasonably clear

```py
import psycopg2, urllib2

image_url = 'http://example.com/theimage.jpg'
image_data = urllib2.urlopen(image_url).read()
media_id = 3

# triple quotes allows better string formating
sql = """
    with s as (
        select media_id 
        from images 
        where media_id = %(media_id)s
    )
    insert into images (media_id, data)
    select %(media_id)s, %(data)s
    where not exists (select 1 from s)
    returning media_id
;"""

# a parameter dictionary is clearer than a tuple
data_insert_image = {
    'media_id': media_id,
    'data': psycopg2.Binary(image_data)
}

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=db user=u password=p")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, data_insert_image)
# fetchone returns a single tuple or null
result = cursor.fetchone()
conn.commit()

if result is not None:
    print 'Media Id {0} was inserted'.format(result[0])
else:
    print 'Media Id {0} already exists'.format(media_id)
```

Comment: does we have select here as  psycopg2.Binary ?