# Postgresql insert if not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm very new to SQL, and all I get is error after error, so any help would be appreciated.

I have a tags table: id, name, slug

I've Google'd, searched on Stackoverflow, but nothing works for me. I'm trying to create a tag if it doesn't exist, but always return the ID whether it's created or exists.

```
INSERT INTO tags (name, slug)
SELECT ('Wow', 'wow')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE slug = 'wow')
RETURNING id;
```

Here's what I have: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4050a/18

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres: INSERT if does not exist already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069718/postgres-insert-if-does-not-exist-already)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't put the columns in parentheses.

If you look at the full error message you get, then Postgres actually tells you what was wrong.

> ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
>    Hint: The insertion source is a row expression containing the same number of columns expected by the INSERT. **Did you accidentally use extra parentheses?**

The expression `('Wow', 'wow')` is just a *single* column, an anonymous "record" with two variables (See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#AEN7362) for details)

```
INSERT INTO tags (name, slug)
SELECT 'Wow', 'wow'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE slug = 'wow')
RETURNING id;
```

In general it's a good idea to add parentheses only if they are really **required**

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes it is. Because the `insert` specifies *two* columns whereas the `select` only has a single column thus it generates an error: "*INSERT has more target columns than expressions*"

Comment: . . Thank you, that clarifies it.

Comment: Which is the use of RETURNING id;? Do we really need this?

Answer (score 3):

(1) Just remove the brackets. That should solve your problem.

```
INSERT INTO tags (name, slug)
SELECT 'Wow', 'wow'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE slug = 'wow')
RETURNING id;
```

(2) Try this. That should also do it (even though a FROM
clause is not actually needed as others pointed out).

```
INSERT INTO tags (name, slug)
SELECT 'Wow', 'wow' FROM tags 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE slug = 'wow') 
LIMIT 1
RETURNING id;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have LIMIT 1 there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But my previous answer was better, this is too verbose, too many unnecessary things here.

Comment: @daryl Sure, NP :) No worries.