# What happens with duplicates when inserting multiple rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, exception, duplicates, upsert

I am running a python script that inserts a large amount of data into a Postgres database, I use a single query to perform multiple row inserts:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES ('v1','v2'),('v3','v4') ... etc
```

I was wondering what would happen if it hits a duplicate key for the insert. Will it stop the entire query and throw an exception? Or will it merely ignore the insert of that specific row and move on?

Comment: Basic information is missing: Postgres version, table definition showing all constraints.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `INSERT` will just insert all rows and ***nothing*** special will happen, **unless** you have some kind of [**constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html) disallowing duplicate / overlapping values (`PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE`, `CHECK` or `EXCLUDE` constraint) - which you did not mention in your question. But that's what you are probably worried about.

Assuming a `UNIQUE` or PK constraint on `(col1,col2)`, you are dealing with a textbook `UPSERT` situation. Many related questions and answers to find here.

Generally, if *any* constraint is violated, an exception is raised which (unless trapped in subtransaction like it's possible in a procedural server-side language like plpgsql) will roll back not only the statement, but the ***whole transaction***.

#### Without concurrent writes

I.e.: No other transactions will try to write to the same table at the same time.

- Exclude rows that are already in the table with `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` or any other applicable technique:
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- And don't forget to remove duplicates *within* the inserted set as well, which would *not* be excluded by the semi-anti-join `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`

One technique to deal with both at once would be `EXCEPT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2)
VALUES
  (text 'v1', text 'v2')  -- explicit type cast may be needed in 1st row
, ('v3', 'v4')
, ('v3', 'v4')  -- beware of dupes in source
EXCEPT SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl;
```

[**`EXCEPT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) without the key word `ALL` folds duplicate rows in the source. If you know there are no dupes, or you don't want to fold duplicates silently, use `EXCEPT ALL` (or one of the other techniques). See:

- [Using EXCEPT clause in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329419/using-except-clause-in-postgresql/35329553#35329553)

Generally, if the target table is *big*, `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in combination with `DISTINCT` on the source will probably be faster:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2)
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT *
   FROM  (
       VALUES
         (text 'v1', text'v2')
       , ('v3', 'v4')
       , ('v3', 'v4')  -- dupes in source
      ) t(c1, c2)
   ) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl
   WHERE  col1 = t.c1 AND col2 = t.c2
   );
```

If there can be many dupes, it pays to fold them in the source first. Else use one subquery less.

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

#### With concurrent writes

Use the Postgres `UPSERT` implementation [**`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) in **Postgres 9.5** or later:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1,col2)
SELECT DISTINCT *  -- still can't insert the same row more than once
FROM  (
   VALUES
     (text 'v1', text 'v2')
   , ('v3','v4')
   , ('v3','v4')  -- you still need to fold dupes in source!
  ) t(c1, c2)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;  -- ignores rows with *any* conflict!
```

Further reading:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)
- [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46477/3684)

Documentation:

- [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)
- [The commit page](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/3/35/)
- [The Postgres Wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT)

Craig's reference answer for `UPSERT` problems:

- [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/17267423#17267423)

Answer (score 1):

Will it stop the entire query and throw an exception? Yes.

To avoid that, you can look on the following SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069718/postgres-insert-if-does-not-exist-already), which describes how to avoid Postgres from throwing an error for multiple inserts when some of the inserted keys already exist on the DB.

You should basically do this:

```
INSERT INTO DBtable
        (id, field1)
    SELECT 1, 'value'
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT id FROM DBtable WHERE id = 1
);
```