# Using EXCEPT clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, except

I am trying to use the `EXCEPT` clause to retrieve data from table. I want to get all the rows from `table1` except the one's that exist in `table2`.
As far I understand, the following would not work:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(pk_id int, fk_id_tbl2 int);
CREATE TABLE table2(pk_id int);

Select fk_id_tbl2
FROM table1
Except
Select pk_id
FROM table2
```

The only way I can use `EXCEPT` seems to be to select from the same tables or select columns that have the same column name from  different tables.

Can someone please explain how best to use the explain clause?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your query seems perfectly valid:

```sql
SELECT fk_id_tbl2 AS some_name
FROM   table1
EXCEPT  -- you may want to use EXCEPT ALL
SELECT pk_id
FROM   table2;
```

Column ***names*** are irrelevant to the query. You just need the same number of columns, and their ***data types*** must match. The output column name of your query is `fk_id_tbl2`, just because it's the column name in the first `SELECT`. You can use any alias (`some_name` in my example).

What's often overlooked: the subtle differences between `EXCEPT` (which folds duplicates) and `EXCEPT ALL` - which keeps all individual unmatched rows. If there are no dupes to begin with, `EXCEPT ALL` is the better (faster) choice. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- [`EXCEPT` in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT)