# PostgreSQL Function returning result set from dynamic tables names

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

In my database, I have the standard app tables and backup tables.  Eg.  for a table "employee", I have a table called "bak_employee".  The bak_employee table is a backup of the employee table.  I use it to restore the employee table between tests.

I'd figure I can use these "bak_" tables to see the changes that have occurred during the test like this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee EXCEPT SELECT * FROM bak_employee
```

This will show me the inserted and updated records.  I'll ignore the deleted records for now.

Now, what I would like to do is go through all the tables in my database to see if there's any changes in any of the tables.  I was thinking of doing this as a function so it's easy to call over and over.  This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.show_diff()
  RETURNS SETOF diff_tables AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
  app_tables text;
BEGIN

    FOR app_tables IN
        SELECT table_name  

        FROM   information_schema.tables 

        WHERE  table_catalog = 'myDatabase' 
          AND  table_schema = 'public'
          AND  table_name not like 'bak_%'          -- exclude existing backup tables
    LOOP

        -- somehow loop through tables to see what's changed something like:
        EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || app_tables || ' EXCEPT SELECT * FROM bak_' || app_tables;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But obviously this isn't going to return me any useful information.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `except` won't show you all differences. something like `select * from employee e full outer join bak_employee b on e.id = b.id where e is distinct from b` would be better.

Comment: This can't really be done with a "universal" function because the function can return only one "thing". But those tables will have different number of columns and a result set needs to have the same number of columns for **all** rows. What could work is to return each of the rows as a JSON document or a `hstore` that contains the modified columns as keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return different well-known row types from the same function in the same call. A cheap fix is to cast each row type to `text`, so we have a common return type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.show_diff()
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS   -- text!!
$func$
DECLARE
   app_table text;
BEGIN
   FOR app_table IN
      SELECT table_name  
      FROM   information_schema.tables 
      WHERE  table_catalog = 'myDatabase' 
      AND    table_schema = 'public'
      AND    table_name NOT LIKE 'bak_%'   -- exclude existing backup tables
   LOOP
      RETURN NEXT ' ';
      RETURN NEXT '=== ' || app_table || ' ===';
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
        'SELECT x::text FROM (TABLE %I EXCEPT ALL TABLE %I) x'
       , app_table, 'bak_' || app_table);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.show_diff();
```

I had the test [suggested by @a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550856/postgresql-function-returning-result-set-from-dynamic-tables-names#comment62592309_37550856) at first, but after [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550856/postgresql-function-returning-result-set-from-dynamic-tables-names/37558851#comment62971153_37558851) I realized that there is no need for this. `EXCEPT` considers `NULL` values to be *equal* and shows *all* differences.

While being at it, I improved and simplified your solution some more. Use `EXCEPT ALL`: cheaper and does not run the risk of folding complete duplicates.

- [Using EXCEPT clause in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329419/using-except-clause-in-postgresql/35329553#35329553)

`TABLE` is just syntactical sugar. See:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)

However, **if** you have an index on a unique (combination of) column(s), a `JOIN` like I suggested before should be faster: finding the only possible duplicate via index should be substantially cheaper.

Crucial element is the cast the row type to `text` (**`x::text`**).

You can even make the function work for any table - but never more than one at a time: With a polymorphic parameter type:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: Awesome!!!!  Love your solution.  Except I changed the select statement a bit:SELECT x::text FROM (SELECT * FROM %I EXCEPT SELECT * FROM %I) as x

Comment: @Steven: You are right, `EXCEPT` should work just fine. Or better, yet: `EXCEPT ALL`. The join *may* be faster, though. Consider the update.