# psycopg2 ignore duplicate key violation on multi-row insert

Tags: python, postgresql, bulkinsert, psycopg2

I am executing the following code, however, occasionally, a duplicate key violation would occur and the entire insert would stop. How to ignore such errors and let the query execute for the valid entries?

code:

```
query_data = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s)', row) for row in data)
insert_q = "INSERT INTO <table> VALUES {0};".format(query_data)

try:
   cur.execute(insert_q)                    
except psycopg2.Error:
   self.logger.exception('Database error')

con.commit()
```

UPDATE 2:

I posted my own answer below which solved the problem. It uses the new ON CONFLICT syntax in Postgres.

UPDATE 1:

There was a problem about commiting inside the except block, however, what I found was, if you don't all the other inserts won't execute giving the following error:

```
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

To avoid the confusion, added the commit after the try except

Comment: That's not something you do in the query. It's something you set up when creating the table (or can tack on by altering the table).

Comment: Also, why are you committing inside of the `except` block?

Comment: If you don't, all the other queries that follow will not get executed too. This is only a sample of the code.

Comment: Well yes, that would be the point of not committing...

Answer (score 5):

Following is the working code (with the query):

```
query_data = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s)', row) for row in data)
insert_q = "INSERT INTO <table> VALUES {0} ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;".format(query_data)

try:
   cur.execute(insert_q)                    
except psycopg2.Error:
   self.logger.exception('Database error')

con.commit()
```

Find more on this here: [What happens with duplicates when inserting multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875185/what-happens-with-duplicates-when-inserting-multiple-rows)

Comment: What's the equivalent for multi-row update?

Comment: how can I capture all the entries which are having the conflicts, so I can take action on those afterwards?