# Why postgresql encount duplicate key when key not exists?

Tags: postgresql

When I am inserting data into Postgresql(9.6),throw this error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "book_intial_name_isbn_isbn10_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name, isbn, isbn10)=(三銃士, , ) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

I add uniq constraint on columns `name, isbn, isbn10`.But when I check the distination table,it does not contains the record:

```
select * from public.book where name like '%三銃%';
```

How to fix?This is my insert sql:

```
insert into public.book
select *
from public.book_backup20190405 legacy
where legacy."name" not in
(
    select name
    from public.book
)
limit 1000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875185/what-happens-with-duplicates-when-inserting-multiple-rows/30878260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An educated guess, there may be more than one row in the source table `book_backup20190405` which has the unique key tuple `('三銃', '', '')`.

Since the bulk `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` will be be transactional, you'll be none the wiser to the error, since all data will have been rolled back when the constraint fails.

You can verify this by running a dupe check on the source table:

```
SELECT name, isbn, isbn10, COUNT(*) 
FROM public.book_backup20190405 
WHERE name = '三銃' 
GROUP BY name, isbn, isbn10 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

To see if there are duplicates.

Here's an example of how the source table can be the sole source of duplicates:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29ba3