# PostgreSQL Insert Random Values Into Table And Avoid Duplication For Rows With The Same Type

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a database table in PostgreSQL called "item" that have 3 columns

```
id: UUID
name: VARCHAR
type: VARCHAR
```

The "id" column is a primary key and there is no other constraint or index in this table.

My requirements are: if two rows have the same name, they should not have the same type which means the same type can not be attached to the same name more than once.

**Here is my question:**
How to insert a new row with maintaining my previous condition and taking into consideration the race condition that night happen with concurrent transactions?

I have already read about conditional insert (using WHERE NOT EXIST) but it has a caveat as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342031/7972923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put unique index on (name,type)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX your_idx ON items (name, type);
```

This will ensure that there are no two duplicates on (name, type) tuple which I believe achieves
`if two rows have the same name, they should not have the same type`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I can also use a unique constraint on multiple columns, right?

Comment: Exactly, https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-unique-index/ see multiple columns example