# How to limit my user creation method to one transaction at the time? (Container vs Transaction managed Concurrency)

Tags: postgresql, cdi, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am using a **ContainerRequestFilter** that checks if a user already exists in my DB. **If not, it calls a service to create it**:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    // [...]
    @Inject
    JsonWebToken jwt;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
            UserAccount userAccount = userAccountService.createIfNotExistsBySubjectId(jwt.getSubject());
        }
    }
}
```

The service bean:

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserAccountService {
    // [...]
    @Transactional
    public UserAccount createIfNotExistsBySubjectId(String subjectId) {       
        UserAccount userAccount = UserAccount.find("subjectId", subjectId).withLock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).firstResult();
        if (userAccount == null) {
            log.info(MessageFormat.format("Creating new user account for subjectId {0}.", subjectId));
            UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount(subjectId)
            userAccount.persistAndFlush();
        } 
        return userAccount;
    }
}
```

With this, I am encountering **race conditions when I send multiple requests simultaneously**. Two threads are calling my method:

[image]

... resulting in an obvious SQL error:

[image]

To solve this, I tried two approaches:

- The [Quarkus Panache Documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#second-locking-in-a-find) states that I can **lock a find operation** - hence the LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE in my service.
- The [Quarkus CDI Documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#container-managed-concurrency) states that I can enforce **Container-managed Concurrency** by using the annotation io.quarkus.arc.Lock. I tried to apply it on my createIfNotExistsBySubjectId, but to no avail.

**What am I doing wrong?**
I want to ensure that the user creation method is called in a blocked manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you do a read/check/update operation against a remote system, you are going to get issues like this.

What you need to do is utilize the Database's "upsert" feature. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742830/2504224 on how to create a proper query in PostgreSQL

Comment: Why do the LockModeType and the io.quarkus.arc.Lock annotation exist then? Aren't they supposed to fix my very problem? Also, this is not supported by Panache 

Comment: It's a concurrency mechanism for beans, it has nothing to do with database access